# Controlling third-part application

Tags: c#, pinvoke, emulation

I want to send keyboard events to another application, more specifically, a gameboy emulator.

I have tried using many different methods of the User32.dll. None worked as I want.

I have the following window:

[image]

I tried sending data with the code:

```
        var p = Process.GetProcessesByName("VisualBoyAdvance-M").FirstOrDefault();
        if (p != null)
        {
            IntPtr h = p.MainWindowHandle;
            SetForegroundWindow(h);
        }

        while (true)
        {
            SendKeys.SendWait("{DOWN}");
            Console.WriteLine("DOWN");
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
        }
```

The "down" is a command to the down on the game. When I do it, the emulator should move the arrow down.
When I run the code above, the emulator becomes the active window. But the only thing that moves are the menu items, if I click on one. The selection moves up and down. Example:

[image]

I have also tried (with no success):

```
        var p = Process.GetProcessesByName("VisualBoyAdvance-M").FirstOrDefault();
        if (p == null) return;

        IntPtr Hwnd = p.MainWindowHandle;
        SetForegroundWindow(Hwnd);

        while (true)
        {
            SendMessage(Hwnd, WindowsAPI.WM_KEYDOWN, uint.MinValue, int.MinValue);
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            SendMessage(Hwnd, WindowsAPI.WM_KEYUP, uint.MinValue, int.MinValue);
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            SendMessage(Hwnd, WindowsAPI.WM_KEYDOWN, uint.MinValue, int.MinValue);
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
        }
```

I have no idea how to select the window I need and start sending the commands to it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the emulator once you can communicate with it. You may be able to do what you want to do directly without resorting to sending keyboard signals with the proper libraries/emulator. This is a example of a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), ask about the problem you want to solve not the problem you have with the solution you came up with for the original problem.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain , I want to integrate it with an ircbot, to control it remotely. The problem is that I can send the events, but only to the menu, not to the game itself.

Comment: You don't appear to make any effort to find the game window. Most likely the game is in a different window from the main app window. Use Spy++ to understand the hierarchy. Rather then SendMessage consider faking input using SendInput. In .net that's exposed through SendKeys.

Answer (score 0):

Try using WINAPI SendMessage function to send WM_CHAR or WM_KEYDOWN/WM_KEYUP events.

Comment: I have just changed the post to an easier emulator, but the issue is the same. I can't send the events to the game.